# How to auto select a value according to current post in wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, contact-form-7

I am trying to display auto select a value on a `single-services.php` page and services is my custom post type. on the `single-services.php` page I am having a select box that shows all the services posts title in the option created by the contact form 7 plugin. I wonder how to auto-select the option value according to the current service post visited by the user.

**This is my function that adds all the service posts in the select box in functions.php**

```
function add_posttype_to_CF7 ( $tag, $unused ) {
    if ( $tag['name'] != 'services' ){
          //continue only for the specific field - here we check by the name of the field
          return $tag;
    }

    //get a list of all active services
    $services = get_posts(array(
        'post_type' => 'service',
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'posts_per_page' => -1
    ));

    foreach ( $services as &$services ) {
        $tag['raw_values'][] = $services->post_title;
        $tag['values'][] = $services->post_title;
        $tag['labels'][] = $services->post_title;

    }
    return $tag;
}

add_filter( 'wpcf7_form_tag', 'add_posttype_to_CF7', 10, 2);
```

Comment: Did you tried the `get_queried_object()` inside your `add_posttype_to_CF7` function? This way you may get the information you desire, and thus handle the selected value your self. I am not sure if you can declare the selected value from the `wpcf7_form_tag` but if you can, maybe the `get_queried_object()` can help.

Comment: Alternatively, you may write some javascript code, something like: `<script type="text/javascript">let select = document.querySelector('select.services_field'); select && select.val = '<?php $queried_object = get_queried_object(); echo $queried_object->ID; ?>'</script>`.

Comment: @KodeFor.Me thanks for answering yes I got the current post By `get_queried_object()` but I resolve my issue. Anyway thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my issue with JQuery.

```
<script>
jQuery(document).ready( function($) {
    var h1Text = "<?php echo $service_title ?>";
    jQuery('#service_id[name="services"]').find('option[value="'+h1Text+'"]').prop("selected",true); 
});</script>
```